# Main site reporting 0 visitors per day

Tags: bug, status-completed, statistics

On the main site right now, this site's traffic is reported as 0 visitors per day:

[image]

This was reproduced by one other person in the main Anime & Manga chatroom. Area51 currently shows us with 741 visits, which is a lot more than 0:

[image]

This is likely to go away on it's own given enough time, but I'm submitting the bug report anyway in case it indicates a more serious issue with the visit counting.

---

**Update**: As of 7:53 UTC, this is now showing 723, which is a more reasonable number (and which agrees with what Area51 had yesterday). As long as it doesn't happen again I guess it can be safely ignored.

Comment: The one on the main site seems to lag by 12 hours (it displays the previous one displayed by Area 51 +/- 1; the previous Area 51 was 723, so I'd expect 722, 723, or 724). Regardless it does seem to be fixed now. Good spotting, though.

Comment: I guess this is a good place to mention for posterity that this phenomenon seems to occur occasionally, probably because some internal lookup failed or something. I've seen it 2 or 3 more times in the past year. It is typically fixed within a couple of hours. So for any future bug reports related to this statistic, first wait to see if the situation corrects itself.